# Magento 2.3.3 Upgrade Error - You cannot define a correlation name 'stock_item' more than once

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, stock

**Getting Error on Bundle Product page on Magento 2.3.3 after Upgrade.**

Exception #0 **(Zend_Db_Select_Exception):** You cannot define a correlation name 'stock_item' more than once
[image]

**Thanks**

Comment: please run reindex and flush command after the check log file may help you.

Comment: reindex and flush done. also check log file but didn't understand the error.

Comment: disable third party extension may generate an issue after check

Comment: // function getPriceList()  -> magento\module-bundle\Pricing\Adjustment\DefaultSelectionPriceListProvider.php

/****** comment Out the below Line then problem is slove But don't know why it is used for in magento2.3.3 ********/

//$selectionsCollection->addQuantityFilter();

Comment: first, are you a diable extension or not before comment code?

Comment: we have lots of custom module and 3rd party extension so not disable the extension.

Comment: yes but you easily find which extension has an issue after compatible so next time error may not occur.

Comment: If any extension may cause error why it's not showing Logs on attached screenshot.

Comment: some time error does not generate but after run compile command gives an error.